# TextFieldParser Not Setting EndOfData field

Tags: c#, parsing, textfieldparser

I have a `Validate(Stream inputStream)` method.  This method calls several other validation methods by passing the **inputStream** to each one.  Each of these creates a new `TextFieldParser` and reads/validates the file.

When the first `ValidateA(inputStream)` is called, it works.  But, when the 2nd `ValidateB(inputStream)` is called, the `parser.EndOfData` is **true** so, it does not read the fields.

I've tried to clean up the code to its simplest form.

```
public int Validate(Stream inputStream, ref List<string> errors)
{
    inputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);  
    errors.AddRange(ValidateA(inputStream));

    // The 2nd time, the EndOfData is true, so it doesn't read the fields
    inputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    errors.AddRange(ValidateB(inputStream));
...
}

private List<string> ValidateA(Stream inputStream)
{
    List<string> errors = new List<string>();
    // Works fine the first time
    using (var parser = new TextFieldParser(inputStream))
    {
        parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
        parser.SetDelimiters(",");
        parser.TrimWhiteSpace = true;
        int lineNumber = 0;

        while (!parser.EndOfData)
        {
            string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
            // Processing....
        }

        if (lineNumber < 2)
            errors.Add(string.Format("There is no data in the file"));
    }
    return errors;
}
```

Here is where the problem occurs.  The ValidateB method cannot process the file because the `EndOfData` field does not get reset.

```
private List<string> ValidateB(Stream inputStream)
{
    List<string> errors = new List<string>();
    using (var parser = new TextFieldParser(inputStream))
    {
        parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
        parser.SetDelimiters(",");
        parser.TrimWhiteSpace = true;
        int LineNumber = 0;
        while (!parser.EndOfData)
        {
          // Processing....
        }
    }

    return errors;
}
```

Comment: I've also tried copying the inputStream to a new Stream just to see if it would reset.

Comment: So you know that Seek() is not actually implemented on the *concrete* class that inherits from Stream.   Whatever it might be, the debugger tells you.  There's a programmer somewhere that deserves a nastygram from you for not throwing InvalidOperationException, we can't help you find him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment by @HansPassant is correct and lead me to change the way I was passing data around.  Instead of passing a `Stream` around, I converted the `MemoryStream` to a `byte[]`.

Then, in the `ValidateX(byte[] fileByteArray)` method, I would create a new `MemoryStream` from the byte array and use it.

Example:

```
Stream stream = model.PostedFile.InputStream;
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
stream.CopyTo(memStream);
byte[] data = memStream.ToArray();
var result = ValidateB(data);
```

And then,

```
private List<string> ValidateB(byte[] fileByteArray)
{
    List<string> errors = new List<string>();
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fileByteArray);
    ms.Position = 0;
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    using (var parser = new TextFieldParser(ms))
    {
        // Processing...
    }

}
```

This prevented problems with the `EndOfData` and trying to access a Stream that was closed.